# Implement both http basic and forms login on the same springboot application

Tags: authentication, spring-boot

I want to implement http basic authentication for the path '/api/' and forms authentication for the paths '/' and '/admin' of my springboot application.

This is my current java config code, but it is not working, any ideas? =)
This code makes all the site to be secured with http basic, not just '/api'. I have found some questions in stackoverflow but they dont seem to solve my issue:

```
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/inicio");
        http.logout().permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    http.csrf().disable();
}
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and had to split the Basic and Form Authentication.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FormSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests() //
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() //
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") //
            .and() //
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/inicio").permitAll() //
            .and() //
            .logout();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class BasicSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.antMatcher("/api/**") //
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated() //
            .and() //
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances

Comment: Works like a charm. I just had to add two minor changes to your code: 1: added 'permitAll()' to the login form because it was giving me an 'infinite redirect' error on the login page: .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/inicio") and added http.csrf.disable() to the forms auth configuration (it was giving me a 'missing CSRF token' error after login (I'll do more research about CSRF later). Thanks!

Comment: you can mark my answer as correct. i edited my answer to add the permitAll(). CSRF token is a security measure, in you login page you have to add a _csrf parameter containing the token sent by the server http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token

Comment: updated link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6-SNAPSHOT/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity

Answer (score 0):

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated now (spring security 6.0 and higher)
So we can rewrite the above code as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{
public SecurityFilterChain 
filterchain(HttpSecurity http) throws 
Exception {

http.authorizeRequests()
        
.requestMatchers("/**")
.authenticated()
       
.requestMatchers("/admin/**")
.hasRole("ADMIN") 
.formLogin(login -> 
login.loginPage("/login") 
.defaultSuccessUrl("/inicio")
.permitAll()
.logout();
   }
}

@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class BasicSecurityConfig {

public SecurityFilterchain 
filterchain(HttpSecurity http) 
throws 
Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.requestMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .httpBasic();
         }
     }
```